# Automatic horizontally scrolling textview getting initialized everytime an image is changing in runnable

Tags: java, android, firebase, textview

I have developed an app in which I have a textview whose text keeps scrolling automatically. I also have  an imageview whose image keeps changing automatically after every four seconds. To accomplish this I have created a new runnable having 4 seconds time. Suppose there are 5 images which gets displayed. The problem is every time a new image is loaded in imageview the text of textview gets reset and it starts scrolling from beginning and this happens only for the first iteration of all the images. After all images are displayed once then from the next iteration onwards the textview starts behaving properly and the text doesn't resets. I don't know what is the problem. Here is the code

```
//In onCreate
headlinesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_news);
        headlinesText.setSelected(true);


//This is a separate method

public void settingAds() {
        myRef.child("Advertisements").addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                imageUrl.clear();
                for (com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot eachAdUrl : dataSnapshot.child("Adurls").getChildren()) {
                    imageUrl.add(String.valueOf(eachAdUrl.getValue()));
                }
                headlineFromFirebase = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("News").getValue());
                adTimer = (long) dataSnapshot.child("Time").getValue();
                headlinesText.setText(headlineFromFirebase);

                /*headlinesText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewsList.class));
                    }
                });*/

                //Randomly shuffling the array list
                Collections.shuffle(imageUrl);

                for(int i=0;i<imageUrl.size();i++) {
                    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                            .load(imageUrl.get(i))
                            .fetch();
                }
                //runnable code was here
                if(handler != null) {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                }
                handler = new Handler();
                runnable = new Runnable() {
                    int imageCounter=0;
                    public void run() {
                        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                                .load(imageUrl.get(imageCounter))
                                .fit()
                                .centerCrop()
                                .into(mAdsView);
                        imageCounter++;
                        if (imageCounter > imageUrl.size()-1) {
                            imageCounter = 0;
                        }
                        handler.postDelayed(this,adTimer);
                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 250);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It seems that you are not changing the headline text in the runnable. The text is changed only once in the onDataChange method.

Comment: I dont want to change text. The text is constant only image needs to change every 4 seconds

Comment: where is the code for scrolling text then?

Comment: with scrolling text code I meant the java code! Could you post it?

Comment: yes I understood that the java code is only two lines for textview and the rest of the logic code I have already posted